# Criação de Programa em Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou fazendo um exercício:

> Uma fábrica tem 10 representantes. Cada um recebe uma comissão calculada a partir do número de itens de um pedido, segundo os seguintes critérios:
>   – para até 19 itens vendidos, a comissão é de 10% do valor total do pedido;
>   – para pedidos de 20 e 49 itens, a comissão é de 15% do valor total do pedido;
>   – para pedidos de 50 a 74 itens, a comissão é de 20% do valor total do pedido; e
>   – para pedidos iguais ou superiores, a 75 itens a comissão é de 25%.
>
> Faça um programa que lê a quantidade de itens de pedidos de cada representante e imprime o percentual de comissão de cada um.

Eu pensei em criar uma variável para cada entrada, ou seja, uma variável para cada representante e no final para gerar as comissões colocando vários if elif e else. A minha pergunta é com deixar esse código mais enxuto sem eu ter que criar as 10 variáveis?

Mais ou menos eu fiz esse pedaço de código que me da as 10 entradas. Só que daqui para a frente eu me enrolei na hora de criar os condicionais para gerar o valor de cada comissão de cada representante.

Meu esboço de código, com as entradas:

```
print ("\n--------------------------------------------------------")
print ("\n--------------------------------------------------------")


def exercicio():    
    itens = []    
    item = 0

    while item == 0:
        item = float(input("\nQuantidade de Itens do 1º Representante: "))
        if item < 0:
            print("\nAs Quantidades não podem ser menores que Zero.")
            itens.append(item)


    for i in range(9):
        item = float(input("\nQuantidade de Itens do %dº Representante: " % (i+2)))
        itens.append(item)



   print("\n",item)
   print ("\n",itens)


exercicio()

print ("\n--------------------------------------------------------")
print ("\n--------------------------------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você se perdeu na lógica do seu código. Você imprime uma mensagem de que valores menores que 0 são inválidos, mas o armazena mesmo assim. Além disso a mensagem de erro só é imprimida se o primeiro valor for inválido, e ignora todos os demais.

A quantidade poderia ser tratada dessa maneira

```
for i in range(10):
    item = int(input("\nQuantidade de itens do %dº representante: " % (i+1)))
    while item < 0:
        item = int(input("\nA quantidade não pode ser menor que zero, digite novamente: "))
```

E as comissões poderiam ser guardadas num array, assim como a quantidade de itens vendidos

```
comissoes = []
for item in itens:
    comissao = '10%' if item < 20 else \
               '15%' if item < 50 else \
               '20%' if item < 75 else \
               '25%'
    comissoes.append(comissao)
```

Comment: Poxa. Muito Obrigado Ajudou Muito.